# Knitr plotting outside margin

Tags: floats, margins, plot, knitr

I like the look of plots that extend beyond the margins

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{}}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

What options do I need to specify in a `knitr` chunk to achieve this effect? The option `fig.width` appears to only change the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) `out.width=".9\\paperwidth"`.

---

**Update:**

knitr does not have the full power of LaTeX (that is too much to do in pure R). If you want more control over LaTeX, you can consider the chunk option `fig.show='hide'` or `fig.show='hold'` and hard-code the LaTeX part later, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
<<test-plot, fig.height=3, fig.show='hide'>>=
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1)); plot(1:10)
@

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\paperwidth]{figure/test-plot}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

There is a disadvantage in this approach, which is the figure path is hard-coded instead of dynamically generated from the chunk label, so you will have to be very careful to synchronize these two places.

Comment: The plot isn't centred in the page like the `makebox[\textwidth]{` option is.

Comment: That makes it more complicated... see edited answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, the only real downside to this approach (apart from the extra code) is that if I change the chunk title I have to change the `\includegraphics` argument?

Comment: @Hugh yes, that is the only possible problem